# how to populate a ajax response the reponse is in json format into a input text field

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to display the response data in JSON format in the input text box.

I have tried to append its value of the input text box.

```
<input type="text"  id="vmname" class="namedes form-control"/>


success: function (response) {

       let data = []; let options = '';

      $.each(response, function (key, value) {
         options += 'value=' + value["Virtualmachinename"];

              });
               $("#vmname").html(options);
               $("#vmname").change();
```

Nothing is getting displayed in the input text box.

Comment: place your html code here with entire js code

Answer (score 0):

The input will be populated with string.

Also add as value to the input but not `html`

```
$("#vmname").val(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery, use `$("#vmname").val(options);`

Without jQuery, use `document.querySelector("#vmname").value = options;`